# Stop Audio before Playing Video file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have two view Controllers, one plays audio files and other plays video files. I am playing audio file in background and it continues to play even if I switch to Video view Controller but when I tap on a video link, audio should stop but it is not stoping.

For audio player I am using `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];`
How can I stop audio before playing video? Is there any way to check in iPhone that a background music is playing?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what are you using as a video player?

Comment: I am using MPMoviePlayerViewController. And solved myself using notification

Answer (score 0):

You can stop sound using below code:

```
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundid);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two controller, you can stop audio switching on the other one. In the "viewWillDisappear" method of the audio controller perform a [setActive:error:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/setActive%3aerror%3a) method.

Comment: I can not do this as I have to keep audio playing even after switching. I want to stop it when tapping on video link.

Comment: If you have control on the tapping of video link you can stop before play video.